# Migration of ETL jobs to Hadoop

Tags: pandas, hadoop, hive, etl

I have a set of ETL (created in informatica) jobs which I want to migrate to Hadoop. I have already created source and target tables into hadoop environment. Now I can write a hive query to implement logic of ETL which pulls data from source and write to target table. But this is lengthy process since my ETL jobs are complex (with complex business logic), development and testing of these queries are taking longer time. I would like to know if there are any better way to migrate my ETL code to Hadoop ? I heard we can use pandas dataframe instead of hive. Any suggestions ?

Comment: No, pandas is not a replacement for Hive. You can use **Spark** Dataframes, but you still need to get data to HDFS

Comment: Spark with Python API (pySpark) will do for you [almost] everything pandas can do.

Comment: As you are migrating from an ETL tool, there is very little code you can lift and shift. Most of your code will have to be re-written to whichever technology you choose. So, the development and testing cost is likely to be similar. Have you considered using Informatca's big data offering? In which case you only have to replace your targets.

Comment: I am removing dependency from Informatica.